# Printen the meta_value from knowing the meta_key

Tags: php, database, wordpress

imagine about what I know and what I need

[image]

I'm trying to get the `meta_value` for a shortcode so I know the `meta_key` and the `post_id` of that I don't know how to get it to work properly I hope someone can help me out?

Comment: As far I can see, you already get it by creating a successful screenshot. So how exactly you wanna get it out this? What you have tried so far as a code where we could help you.

Comment: You are the one supposed to be asking questions, not us. Provide some code.

Comment: if you know the meta_key and  post_id, it's as simple as `$meta_value = get_post_meta($post_id, 'file_upload2', true);` in your shortcode. If you want to use the current post's ID, use `global $post; $meta_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'file_upload2', true);` instead.